# Remove boxes from hyperlinked ToC in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tableofcontents

How do I remove the red boxes from my hyperlinked table of contents created by using the hyperref package in LaTeX.

Comment: For a broader question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-cross-references-and-hyperlinks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To remove the borders:

```
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
```

The `colorlinks` option will turn on the link colors and also remove the borders.  (This is why alamodey set all the link colors to black.)

Comment: Is there a way to do it only for the toc ?

Answer (score 41):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, now I can not only remove the border, but also define the colors of the links.

Comment: Is there a way to set urlcolor to the color of the body text in which the link appears, rather than insisting that color is "black"?

Answer (score 32):

Version 6.82a of hyperref, released in February 2011, introduced a new `hidelinks` option that accomplishes this more easily. All you need now is:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it only for the toc ?

Answer (score 10):

I realize it's a bit late to answer but there's a simpler way, in my experience

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

This will shift hyperref from ugly borders to link coloring, which is what you usually want. See here for more options:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks